# Checking Function inside IF statement explanation

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, equality

I'm declaring a function which is used as a comparison. My question is:

Why does the condition act as a statement?

why does line 4 work but not line 5?

I know this code is unrealistic and unused, but why does the compiler allow this syntax?

There is no answer on google. But then again, I might have not look in the right place.

```
var A = () => console.log(3);

if (A === console.log(1)) {
  A();
};

A ? A() : null;

if (A === console.log(1567)) {};

if (B === console.log(1567)) {};
```

The expected output is:

```
3
```

The output is:

```
1

3

1567
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: B is not defined at :11:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line by line meaning -

1. The very first line defined `A` as an arrow function.
2. Next line comparison - Right to left - `A` is defined and has some value, next `console.log(1)` is a function call so the value of it is "evaluated". And the return value is compared against the defined value of `A` - that turned out to be false (`A` is function reference whereas `console.log()` returns `undefined`).
3. Out of if - offcourse `A` is defined so it calls `A()` - Hence second line output.
4. Again comparison - similar to point(2)
5. Again comparison - but `B` is not defined which is a throwable and hence the error and going from left to right - the `console.log` is never evaluated.

Questions -

1. Condition act as a statement - it is by design - try `if(console.log())` - they are places where code if evaluated to true/false the execution takes direction. And having a statement in that area provides with feature like - `while(true){}` or `while(someFuncIfTrue(2)){}`.
2. Step 4 works but not 5 - point(5) answers that.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `console.log(1)` evaluates to `undefined`. `A` is not `undefined` so none of the comparisons are true.

However before returning `undefined`, `console.log(1)` prints `1` to the console. So the first and third of the output lines in your example come from the evaluation of `console.log(1)` and `console.log(1567)`.

`console.log(1)` is not a closure. The closure is `()=>console.log`.